# Make custom intellij theme apply to UI

Tags: intellij-idea, settings

I downloaded a custom intellij theme and imported it into my project with `file > import settings` then went to `file > settings > Editor > colors & fonts` and chose my color scheme name. This applied well to the code editor, but the UI (such as the project navigation pane) did not change. Do I need to apply the settings to the UI in another manner?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The UI of IntelliJ IDEA uses many different colors, some of which are calculated, as well as graphics which exist in two different versions, regular and Darcula. Because of that, it's currently not possible to change the UI colors to anything other than the default and Darcula themes.

Comment: Do you know if theres any way of editing the graphics inside these themes? ie. finding where it loads those from and possibly editing the resources. Not looking for any official option as I know that doesnt exist but it must be loading those resources from somewhere.

Comment: Yes, of course. IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition is open-source, and you can edit everything you need by modifying the source code - colors, graphics, anything you feel like.

Answer (score 8):

It's not easy to change UI colors of IntelliJ IDEA. You have to install a theme-plugin for that. There is no great choice, but I like `Material Theme UI`.

`Settings` > `Plugins` > `Browse repositories...` > search for *Material Theme UI* > Install

For future googlers: we are talking about UI colors here. Editor colors is a totally different story, changing them is quite simple and there are many, many editor themes out there.

Comment: Since Material Theme UI is open-sourced, theoretically one can modify it to fits their needs, and install the plugin "from disk".